# MySQL - Error in Syntax 1064 with Negative Doubles and Chars

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting an error 1064 in MySQL trying to insert new data into a data table. I've looked up the error already and couldn't find any Stack Overflow questions addressing the problem.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
```

Here is a description of the table:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| coord1lat | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| coord1lon | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| coord3lat | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| coord3lon | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status    | char(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and here is a sample row of what I'm trying to insert:

```
insert into sample_parking_spots (null, 47.60624, -122.299735, 47.60226, -122.299687, 'T');
```

and here is the error I'm getting in return:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null, 47.60624, -122.299735, 47.60226, -122.299687, 'T')' at line 1
```

I apologize if this does end up being a duplicate of a question, but I am very new to MySQL and looked several times through the data row I was trying to insert.

Comment: I believe your syntax should be: `insert into sample_parking_spots (list of columns) values (null,...);`

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I thought you just had to use "values" if you were specifying the columns/field names where you were going to insert the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the Keyword **VALUES**

```
insert into sample_parking_spots VALUES (null, 47.60624, -122.299735, 47.60226, -122.299687, 'T');
```